# External Referrer URL in Rails 3 - from embedded script tag?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I seem to be having a lot of trouble getting a URL referer for an external URL.

My app runs through a script people include on their site:

Like so-

```
<script src="http://0.0.0.0:3000/load.js?upid=10b829af3eef17eb203667f5db56ef930eca062fde4a523b" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

When the page is hit and the script loads, its just matched to a controller action, where the upid is used to look up a record.

That action looks like such:

```
  def remote
    @page = Page.find_by_upid(params[:upid])
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
    end    
  end
```

I'm trying to now see the referring URL, as I want to see where that script tag was embedded.

I have tried the following with 0 luck:

```
    logger.debug "r test: #{request.env['HTTP_REFERER']}"
    logger.debug "r test: #{request.referer}"
    logger.debug "r test: #{request.original_url}"
```

They all either return blank, or this URL `http://0.0.0.0:3000/load.js?upid=10b829af3eef17eb203667f5db56ef930eca062fde4a523b` from the script tag.

Any help would be great

Comment: Are you getting proper referer URLs from any other action?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for future reference, I solved this by grabbing the URL through javascript, within the file thats included in the script tag. Then, because that file is processed by rails first, I was able to send it into a method call with an erb tag to do what I wanted.